# Iterate over ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java

An arraylist contain object of a class. The object contain 3 variable name,city and phonenumber. How to iterate over the arraylist in java.
is this syntax correct: name of the arraylist is cartdetails.

Comment: Well, what syntax are you talking about?

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/techindex/Iterate-a-List-in-Java.html ("first hit" on google; this is why you are receiving -1's)

Answer (score 2):

```
A a;
ArrayList<A> list= new ArrayList<A>();
//add data
Iterator<A> i = list.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    a = i.next();
    System.out.println(a.field1);
    System.out.println(a.field2);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to iterate list is below

```
  ClassA obj1 = new ClassA();
  ClassA obj2 = new ClassA();
  ClassA obj3 = new ClassA();
  ClassA obj4 = new ClassA();

  List<ClassA> list = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
  list.add(obj1);
  list.add(obj2);
  list.add(obj3);
  list.add(obj4);

  foreach( ClassA obj = list  ){

  //here, you can put the processing logic.
  }
```