# How to get the first value in array, then second and so on?

Tags: java, android

I generate and store numbers in an array (these numbers are 1 to 4) I want to have a loop that checks if the first number is 1 and if it is do action, if its not move on to 2 and so on..

```
final ArrayList<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
final int[] NumbersArray = new int[20];
for (int generatedNumbers = 0; generatedNumbers < 2 + temp; generatedNumbers++) {
        value = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
        NumbersArray[generatedNumbers] = value;
```

I tried

```
for(Integer i : NumbersArray) {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        System.out.println("1");
Color1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7F7500"));
                      }
                   else if (i == 2) {
                        else if (i == 2) {
                        System.out.println("2");
Color2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                     }
```

Comment: Why do you have `listInteger`? You don't use it once you create it. What is `builder`?

Comment: why do you need a loop to check if the first number is 1 ?

Comment: You should not be concatenating inside of a `StringBuilder#append`. That defeats the purpose of using one.

Comment: As far as i understand this you want to iterate over an array and check if any value is `1`. This is basic java knowledge and you should be able to do this by yourself! (Since you've already done a loop in your code)

Comment: Do you have different actions for each numbers, 1, 2, 3 &4. You might want to look at switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over ArrayList in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027368/iterate-over-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

```
for(Integer i : listInteger){
   if(i == 1){
    // do smth
    break; // quit loop you found your number 1
    }
}
```

This is how you loop over it.

Comment: what if the number is 2, 3 or 4? do i just have `if(i == 2) { //do stuff}`

Comment: @TroubleSome Wait what? You want to to know what the first number of the array is? Not sure what you are trying...

Comment: yeah, I generate random numbers and store them in an array, then I want to read from that array 1 number after next and do action for that number, so lets say that the numbers generated are 1,4,2,1 I want to do an action for every one of them one by one with a few second delay

Comment: @TroubleSome Then you can use my code without the `if` & `break` statement. The `i` will hold the number

Comment: will that then move onto the next number in the array? or is it just the first one?

Comment: @TroubleSome It will go through every number in the array.

Comment: I tried this but that doesnt work for me, do you see anything wrong with this?
`for(Integer i : listInteger)
{if(i == 1){
red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
red.postDelayed(new Runnable() {public void run() {                                 red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7D0000"));}}, delayTimeMs);} 
else if(i == 1){
red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
red.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {                                 red.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7D0000"));}                          }, delayTimeMs);}`